# How do I receive a file using MuleESB Jersey using PUT or POST?

Tags: http, rest, jersey, mule

I'm using Jersey in Mule v2.2.1 to expose a REST interface.  I having trouble determining how to expose the service and process the file.  For example, I'm looking for something like this:

@POST

@Path ("\processFile")

@Consumes ("plain/text")

void processFile ();

Comment: I am working under the assumption that FileStream can help me, but as yet I haven't got it working:

@PUT

@Path("/processFile")

void processFile(InputStream iStream);

Comment: Found this.  Gonna try it: http://tiainen.sertik.net/2009/10/easy-file-upload-in-java-using-jersey.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an endpoint set up on a TCP socket to get the data from the network to your processFile method?  The method will never get called if you do not.